# code showing segmentation fault

Tags: c++

the following code shows segmentation fault.where is the mistake all i figure out is its in the line containing printf() statement but not sure why is it and how to correct it.Can anyone help me out here..

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<readline/history.h>
#include<readline/readline.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    using_history();
    string command("history");
    add_history(command.c_str());
if (command == "history")
{
    cout<< "hello\n";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < history_length ; i++)
    {
        cout<<"in there\n";
        HIST_ENTRY *entry = history_get(i);
        cout<<"till here\n";
        printf("%5d %s", i , entry->line);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it segfaults on the `printf` call it's safe to assume that the `entry` pointer may be NULL or invalid. It's difficult to tell without seeing more code.

Comment: Well, I'll say what I said on IRC. I would have to imagine that you're using the library incorrectly and that you did not check the result of `history_get` for errors. You should take the time to learn how to use a debugger... we're not here to do that for you for free!

Answer (score 2):

From [the `readline` documentation](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html#SEC12):

> **Function:** `HIST_ENTRY * history_get (int offset)`
>   Return the history entry at position `offset`, starting from `history_base` (see section 2.4 History Variables). If there is no entry there, or if `offset` is greater than the history length, return a NULL pointer.

Your code ignores `history_base` and offsets from 0.

Consequently, `history_get` cannot succeed and is returning a NULL pointer that your code doesn't check for. Attempting to dereference this pointer is causing the segmentation fault.

I'd write the loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < history_length; i++) {
    HIST_ENTRY* entry = history_get(history_base + i);
    if (entry)
       printf("%5d %s", i, entry->line);
    else
       printf("%5d ERROR!", i);
}
```

Notice how I've added the `history_base` offset into my `history_get` call, and added error checking.

**Reading the documentation for the functions that you use, performing error checking and using a debugger are *critical* programming talents!**

Answer (score 0):

The offset parameter to the `history_get(offset);` starts from `history_base`. Also the `history_length` is the total number of entries in history, so you must add the `history_base` in the loop condition.

That means you should rewrite you loop in a following way:

```
for(int i = history_base ; i < history_base + history_length ; i++)

{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'd keep the `0`->`history_length` loop, but add `history_base` to `i` for the call to `history_get`. Vastly simplifies everything.